# Adding a unique FORM name or ID to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way of adding the form name or id to this Function to make it unique? I have a loop process that displays 5 forms and I need this piece of coding to be unique to each.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() { 
        $("input, select, textarea, checkbox, radio").autosave({ 
            url: "/js/autosave/autosave.php", 
            method: "post", 
            grouped: false, 
            success: function(data) { 
                $("#message").html("Data updated successfully"); 
            }, 
            send: function(){ 
                $("#message").html("Sending data..."); 
            }, 
            dataType: "html" 
        });         
    }); 
</script>
```

the form

```
<form action="/js/autosave/autosave.php" method="post"> 
<fieldset> 
<label for="name">Name:<input type="text" name="word" id="word" value="<?php echo $row['word'] ?>"/></label> 
<label for="email">Email:<input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" /></label> 
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['Id'] ?>" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Save changes" /> 
</fieldset> 
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you need to know the form name? Within autosave?

Comment: right... where is the form being returned and used?

Comment: Why does it need a name? Can't you keep a reference to it in a variable and just use that?

Comment: on the function i'm assume... What's happening right now is if I have more than 1 Form on a page the autosave function does not work. So, if I can some how make it unique and have 5 copies load then that should do the trick. edit: i added the FORM to original post.

Comment: Let me know if my answer solves your problem. What it does is finds all forms that don't have an id and gives them one.

Comment: hi hunter, does this get added as a second jscript or appended to the autosave one? and do I have to sent a ID for each form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question...

```
$(function() { 
    var formCounter = 0;
    $("form:not([id])").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id", "form_" + formCounter);
        formCounter++;
    });
}
```

Comment: This would give all forms the same `0` ID.

Comment: @hunter - that happens after `.attr()` acts upon *all* current `<form>` elements.

Comment: If you place that code before the `$("input, select, textarea,...` line, `this` doesn't reference anything useful that would relate it to a particular form. You'd need to be in some sort of loop that makes `this` reference something in the `form`, or the `form` itself.

Comment: That looks better. Just one hint when you use this technique, `.each()` offers you an `index` parameter, so you could get by without incrementing your own `formCounter` variable, though that works as well.

Comment: yes, it does, which would eliminate the need for a counter at all. I guess to be safe it should check if another form doesn't already use that ID which would require some type of independent counter

Answer (score 1):

You could reference `$(this)` within autosave to get the caller and query it for its parent (and add an attribute or some identifying characteristic to each)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('form').each(function(){
        $(this).find('input, select, textarea, checkbox, radio').autosave({
            url: "/js/autosave/autosave.php", 
            method: "post", 
            grouped: false, 
            success: function(data) { 
                $("#message").html("Data updated successfully"); 
            }, 
            send: function(){ 
                $("#message").html("Sending data..."); 
            }, 
            dataType: "html" 
        });
    });
});
```

The code above adds autosave functionality to each form individually, which should solve your issue.

Comment: didn't work i tried it with just one form on a page and still no luck